# App Engine Ruby flex environment app.yaml is ignoring env_variables RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are using GAE with Ruby flexible environment, and we're trying to deploy a rails app with staging configurations (i.e. RAILS_ENV=staging).

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml we should be able to set the value of RAILS_ENV configuring an app.yaml with:

```
env_variables:
  RAILS_ENV: 'staging'
```

However, when we run:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

A (temporary) Dockerfile is generated with

```
# Temporary. Will be moved to base image later.
ENV RACK_ENV=production \
    RAILS_ENV=production \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
```

Which results in a deployment in the PRODUCTION environment (default value for RAILS_ENV).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if StackOverflow is the best place to post this question, as such I also posted the question in "Server Fault": http://serverfault.com/questions/815750/app-engine-ruby-flex-environment-app-yaml-is-ignoring-env-variables-rails-env

Answer (score 1):

The flexible environment sets RAILS_ENV by default to 'production'.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime#environment_variables

Comment: The issue is exactly not being able to set RAILS_ENV to other environment value.. See http://serverfault.com/questions/815750/app-engine-ruby-flex-environment-app-yaml-is-ignoring-env-variables-rails-env

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables set in app.yaml under `env_variables` should now override the defaults (which come from the generated Dockerfile).

I just deployed a [sample application](https://gist.github.com/remi/3ae9562de6aed8680ad1366acaca0690) to App Engine with `RAILS_ENV` customized in my env_variables.

```
env_variables:
  APP_YAML_VAR: this was set in the app.yaml
  RAILS_ENV: overridden
```

When deployed, `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` shows my customized, overridden value.

[Screenshot of customized environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3eub.png)